# Mac Catalina 10.15.4: Could not load Sound preference pane

Tags: macos, catalina, preferences

I selected Volume icon and then `Sound Preferences` in menu bar, but cannot load it. It shows:

> Could not load Sound preference pane

It sometimes happens. How to solve this?

My current workaround: open it as usual, then open `Force Quit Applications` to kill the `System Preference` app, and reopen it again. Usually, after force quitting it will be normal, but it's annoying to do it every time. Also after some time, the bug would happen again.

Comment: Can you add when this happens and have you noticed a pattern? Which machine and OS are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @youngpilot thanks, I've updated it

Comment: In [this post in the Apple Support forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7253713) are a couple of ideas regarding this issue. I'd try those and see if this solves the problem.